# Chart.js - Timeline

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to display dates on xAxes with Chart.js

I tried this with 2 dates but it shows nothing.
Probably something I did wrong with the labels or date format.

```
<canvas id="graph"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["2013-02-08", "2013-02-10"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Something",
                data: [{
                    x: "2013-02-08",
                    y: 1
                }, {
                    x: "2013-02-10",
                    y: 10
                }]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Need help :)

Comment: Please provide a running example. There are quite few parameters involved that should be looked at.

Comment: Please inspect your output in console to see if it gives this type of error `Uncaught Error: Chart.js - Moment.js could not be found! You must include it before Chart.js to use the time scale`, then try to add bundle chart.js version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine except that you don't need to define `data.labels` since the `data` in your dataset is defined as [individual points](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point) through objects containing `x` and `y` properties.

Chart.js internally uses [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for the functionality of the [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "Something",
      data: [
        { x: "2013-02-08", y: 1 }, 
        { x: "2013-02-10", y: 10 }
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="graph"></canvas>
```